# How can I record videos on safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

Hi I have been using the browser camera on my website for users to record a life test, I have used MediaRecorder and it works quite well on chrome and firefox, but not on safari.

Do you know any alternative to MediaRecorder for recording videos from the browser camera with safari?

It can be using the video tag of html, or some html 5, if you have an example of implementation would be much better

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in safari

use the following steps

1. Go to Safari → Preferences → Advanced
2. Enable the option to “Show Develop menu in menu bar” at the bottom
3. Go to Develop → Experimental Features
4. Enable MediaRecorder

Reference [this](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-enable-the-mediarecorder-api-for-safari) document

Or as alternative **Audio Recorder Polyfill**

https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, this I already knew, what I look for is a real solution that the user does not have to do this.

That every user has to do this would be a bad experience, I'm looking for a programmatic solution

Comment: this is only for audio, actually I need to record video without audio

Comment: https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs 

Help this one?